# ipad ssh application with solid copy / paste support

Tags: ipad, ssh, copy-paste

I have been using iSSH on the ipad when I need to ssh to my servers; however, one of the glaring problems with iSSH is that you don't have copy / paste support within the iSSH terminal application (supposedly it is there if you will run VNC, but that is not an option).

Has anyone got an ipad ssh application with good copy / paste functionality?  I need to be able to copy text from within the session and paste it into a browser (and vice versa).

Answer (score 10):

Panic Software recently released [Prompt](http://panic.com/prompt/support.html), the best iOS SSH app I've seen. Copy and paste works great; just double-tap text to bring up the copy/paste dialog (tap-and-hold doesn't work).

Comment: Panic did it all right with Prompt.

Comment: Plus many for prompt. It is superb

Comment: Prompt rules ...